# My conversion from decimal to binary can't deal with negative numbers

Tags: java

I am converting decimal to binary and my code works on positive numbers  but it crashes when I try to convert negative numbers. When it crashes I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

My code is being called from a for loop in main that runs from -8 to +7. 
This is the code for the conversion

```
public char[] decimalToBinary(int value) 
{
    int remainder;
    char[] result = new char[10];
    if (value <= 0)
    {

        return result; 
    }

    remainder = value %2; 
    decimalToBinary(value >> 1);
    System.out.print(remainder);
    return result;
}
```

This is the for loop in main that calls the above method

```
   int min = -8;
   int max = +7;
   for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i) 
   {
        char[] binaryStr = s.decimalToBinary(i);
   }
```

Comment: Why not `Integer.toBinaryString(int)`?

Comment: You are not taking into account the two's complement value of negative integers.

Comment: Because I have to do the conversion myself. thyago stall I tried to set the if (value <= 0) to negative numbers and it crashes. I am not sure what to do

Comment: java also has a `>>>` operator that shifts zero bits into the high-order bit position.

Comment: In your specification, how the negative binary values are supposed to be printed out?

Comment: Besides changing to `if (value == 0)` the bitwise operator needs to be modified to `>>>` since it right pads the integer with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

The example below is a working code based on your logic:

```
public static void decimalToBinary(int value) {
    int remainder;

    if (value == 0) {
        return;
    }

    remainder = value % 2;
    decimalToBinary(value >>> 1);
    System.out.print(remainder);
}
```

You should take into account that the negative numbers will be represented using their **2's complement** values.

Also, the method does not return a `char` array anymore, since it was not being used at all.